# jquery tablesorter pager css issue

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, tablesorter

I'm using a table with tablesorter and tablesorter.pager. Both the table and pager are in a div with a background colour.

The issue I'm having is with the pager. It isn't being contained within the div, and instead floats below it. I assume it's an issue with 'display' or 'position' but whatever I do I can't get it to stay within the bounds of the container div.

Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question...

In the jquery.tablesorter.pager.js file, in the fixPosition function, it is coded to always set the pager to be position: absolute. I've removed this line which solves my problem, but I would be interested to know why this was done!?

Comment: It was added because it moves the pager control box to the bottom of the table. When you have 10 records showing and say you're on the last two, the control stays in the same place as if there were 10 records.

Comment: @pfeds: thanks for your discovery... it works for me, even when a page size of 10 and only 2 records in the last page, the pager is just after the end of the table.

Answer (score 9):

you don't need to remove the fixPosition, you should just set the **positionFixed** to **false**. It's by default *true*.

```
$('table').tablesorterPager({positionFixed: false, container: $("#pager")});
```